# Selector Method to Determine Which Dynamic UIGestureRecognizer Invoked It

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have an indeterminate number of `UIView`s that is only known at runtime. Each of these views must respond to single tap events that are unique to that view. I am using an array to store the information related to each view. Since the number of views will vary, I can't simply write a fixed number of gesture recognizer methods to respond to each tap event.

What I am trying to do is to write a single selector method that will be smart enough to know which `UIView` was tapped that invoked the method. I tried to associate a key value with the gesture recognizer, but that just results in `this class is not key value coding compliant` error. I also though about using another array to store some sort of tag value. But in all cases, I get back to the same basic problem: How can I pass information to my selector method so that it will be able to differentiate which `UIView` was tapped?

Here is how I am populating my `NSMutableArray` that holds pointers to the various `UIView` objects:

```
for (int i=0; i<[self.sessionsList count]; i++ {
    ...

    UIView *frame = [[UIView alloc] init];

    // set up a gesture recognizer to handle tap events for each view
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget : self
                                                                                 action : @selector(playAudio:)];

    // this next line will crash the program if I leave it in
    [singleTap setValue:session_num forKey:@"session_num"]; // associate the session number with this gesture
    [frame addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    [self.buttonsArray addObject:frame];

    ...
}
```

Then, in my selector method, I have this

```
- (void) playAudio : (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"here"); //this will generate output, but not unique to the various views

    // this was my idea for trapping the identifying number of the UIView that was tapped
    NSString *session_num = [recognizer valueForKey:@"session_num"];
    NSLog(@"session_num: %@", session_num);

    // I started to try this, but I don't know how to make it work
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];
    UIView *thisView = [obj hitTest:location withEvent:event];

}
```

I'm pretty stuck on this. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong or have any suggestions for how I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIView doesn't respond to `setValue:forKey` for arbitrary keys. To achieve what you want, you should examine the `view` property of the gesture recogniser in your play audio method. This will reference the view that the gesture recogniser was attached to. If you want, you can do `[self.buttonsArray indexOfObject:recognizer.view]` in your `playAudio:` method to find the index of the button in the array.

Comment: That does exactly what I need. Thanks very much!